# tomcat with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Although i hav installed Tomcat5.5.9 sucessfully, then too i m getting error of javax.servlet.* package does not exist.
how can i resolve it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add [servlet-api.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/) in your class path.

Comment: did u mean tomcat/commom/lib/servlet-api.jar??

Comment: no it will be there @ run time. in order to compile your application and bundle it you need this jar in your class path when you do compilation. put this jar in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: there is no lib folder inside WEB-INF. Did u mean WEB-INf/classes/tomcat5.5.9/lib?

Comment: No. it seems you are developing a web-app . which platform I meant any IDE you are using ???

Comment: i have set the classpath with tomcat\common\lib\servlet-api.jar.buT its still not working...

Comment: I hav added "C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\commom\lib\servlet-api.jar" to my classpath.

Comment: and how do you compile your app ?

Comment: do `javac -cp pathtoyourjar/servletapi.jar Hello.java`

Comment: by javac Hello.java. I hav placed Hello.java in "C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat5.5-9\Webapps\servlets-examples\WEB-INF\classes\Hello.java" and made corrosponding changes to web.xml.

Comment: thanks its compiled successfully. But it is not running at the browser.

Comment: you are welcome :) [go ahead and upvote&mark this as answered].  that can be another question , post it with full descritption

Comment: It is showing the message "the requested resource(\Hello) is not available". How can i resolve it???

Comment: **that can be another question , post it with full descritption**

Comment: near to answer you will see a number that is upvote count. you can press up/down arrow to vote up/down and near to that there is a right mark click it and if its green it is marked .